# Monitor network usage of android device

Tags: android, networking

I'm pretty new to Android programming. I want to monitor network usage of android phone at a specified time interval. Is there any way? Thank you for your guidance.
I'm surfing the internet on this topic and I find out which TrafficStats class is exist to get information about network usage but this class doesn't give network usage at specified time interval.

Comment: You can write service which would be periodically record values from `TrafficStats`. And then get delta. This is variant for all device traffic. 
If you need collect data in app traffic `TrafficStats.setThreadStatsTag` may be useful

Comment: Thanks icebail, your advice helped me somewhat. I need collect total traffic usage of android phone (both TCP and UDP) then turn of wifi and mobile data when this usage exceed a certain amount.